# how to load file by fid in drupal8?

Tags: php, drupal-8

this is my code

```
    $fid=$node->get("field_vocabulary")->audio;
    $file =\Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
    $path = $file->getFileUri();
    $json_arr["audio"]=$path;
```

but it dosnt not work!
why?

show this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getFileUri() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/houdun/drupal/modules/article_json/src/Controller/ArticleJsonController.php on line 91
```

I need help!thanks!

Comment: get file url `File::load()`

Comment: @TARQAT that's not what he meant; he was asking you to clarify what you mean by "doesn't work." Questions asking for debugging help have to have a clear statement of the problem.

Comment: ok,I know your means ,thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it!

```
    $fid=$node->get("field_vocabulary")->audio;
    $file =File::load($fid);
    $path = file_create_url($file->getFileUri());
    $arr["audio"]=$path;
```

or

```
    $fid=$node->get("field_vocabulary")->audio;
    $file =File::load($fid);
    $path = $file->url();
    $arr["audio"]=$path;
```